# Bokeh update a specific list in column with a slider

Tags: python, bokeh

I have to show the internal force in a beam wiht different bearings and different positions of the force. In order to move the force to different positions I want to use the `on_change` function of bokeh with a slider. In order to do that I need to change the values of one list in my `ColumnDataSource` in the class `Froce`. I can creat and plot erverything so far, but when I change the value of the slider it doesn't change the value of the list and niether the position of my force in the graph.

This is the constructor of the calss Force

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
class Force:


list_force =[]

def __init__(self):
    b = Beam.beam_list[0]
    d = 0.2
    self.source_force = dict(x=2*[b.get_x_left()], x_max=2*[(b.get_x_left() + 
    Beam.delta_x)], y=[b.get_y_top(),(b.get_y_top() + 1)], y_end_p= 
    [b.get_y_top(), (b.get_y_top() + d)],
                              x_p1=[b.get_x_left(), (b.get_x_left() + d)], 
    x_p2=[b.get_x_left(), (b.get_x_left() - d)] , d=[d,d], force=[400, 0])
    self.CD_force = ColumnDataSource(data=self.source_force)
    plot.line('x', 'y', source=self.CD_force, color="Blue")
    plot.line('x_p1','y_end_p', source=self.CD_force, color="red")
    plot.line('x_p2', 'y_end_p', source=self.CD_force, color="green")
    Force.list_force.append(self)
    print("Kraft wurde erstellt")
```

and this is the update-function I want to use on the callback event

```
def update_position(sefl, attr, old, new):
    N = new
    force = Force.list_force[0]
    s =slice(2)
    force.CD_force.data['x'] = 2 * [N]
    force.CD_force.patch({'x': [(s, [N, N])]})
```

I have tried to update the `ColumnData` as well as the `dict` but none of this did work.

Here is the plotting part where I create all figuers, sliders, arrange the layout and the callback-function

```
from Klassen import Force, Beam, Get_plot, Bearing
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column

slider_pos = Slider(title="Positoin", start=0, end=8, value=0, step =0.1)
b = Beam(4,8)
Kraft = Force()
f = Bearing.Loslager(b)
slider_pos.on_change('value', Kraft.update_position)
layout = (column(slider_pos, Get_plot()))
show(layout)
```

I've tried to break it down to this basic code, where I want to change the position of the arrow I created. I'm not sure if the `update-funkction` is affected due to the different classes in the different sheets at some point. If it isn't this summuns  up the problem I've got with the updating.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column


plot = figure(plot_height=600, plot_width=400, x_range=(0, 10), y_range= 
       (0,15))

class Force:


    list_force =[]

    def __init__(self):
        d = 0.2
        self.source_force = dict(x=2*[2], x_max=2*[8], y=[3,4], y_end_p=[3, 3 
                                 + d],x_p1=[2, 2 + d], x_p2=[2, 2 - d] , d 
                                 [d,d], force=[400, 0])
        self.CD_force = ColumnDataSource(data=self.source_force)
        plot.line('x', 'y', source=self.CD_force, color="Blue")
        plot.line('x_p1','y_end_p', source=self.CD_force, color="red")
        plot.line('x_p2', 'y_end_p', source=self.CD_force, color="green")
        Force.list_force.append(self)
        print("Kraft wurde erstellt")

    def update_position(sefl, attr, old, new):
        N = new
        force = Force.list_force[0]
        s = slice(2)
        force.CD_force.data['x'] = 2 * [N]
        force.CD_force.patch({'x': [(s, [N, N])]})
        Force.list_force[0] = force


Kraft = Force()
slider_pos = Slider(title="Positoin", start=2, end=8, value=0, step =0.1)
slider_pos.on_change('value', Kraft.update_position)
layout = (column(slider_pos, plot))
show(layout)
```

Comment: Could you create a minimal example to copy in a easier way?

Comment: I*ve created a minimal example at the end of my question. As I added there, I'm not sure if the update is somehow affectet because of the different classes I have to import or not.

Comment: I have solved this issue. You need to run this through a bokeh server. After that it worked totaly fine.